# How to obtain the x and y vectors for those whose state is set to i in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a MATLAB function called `nearInfectious2`, which represents six people. It takes in parameters of an array of `x` coordinates, an array of `y` coordinates, different states relating to those coordinates `"s"` for susceptible, `"i"` for infectious and `"r"` for recovered and lastly a radius. I want to store an array or array(s) of the `x` and `y` coordinates for those people whose state is `"i"`. This is what I have thus far, but it is also including the other coordinates which is not what I want. How can I get it to just return arrays with coordinates relating to those whose state is `"i"`? This is what I have thus far:

```
[x,y]=nearInfectious2([3,350,150,20,204,103],[92,9,200,5,350,34],["s","i","s","r","i","i"],20);
  function [x,y] = nearInfectious2(x,y,states,radius) 

  for j=1:6
        if states(j) == "i"
            x(j)=x(j);
            y(j)=y(j);
        end   
    end 
    disp([x])
    disp([y]) 

end
```

After I have the array of coordinates relating to the people who's states are `"i"`, I want to calculate the distance (using the normal distance formula `sqrt((x2 - x1)^2 + (y2 - y1)^2))` between any individuals whose state is `"s"`, to those whose state is `"i"` to see if it less than radius apart. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, your problem is that your input variables are the same as output and also `x(j)=x(j)` means nothing. You are assigning a value of an array to the same place in the same array.

You should be creating a new array with only the values that match. A quick fix to your code could look like this:

```
function [x_out, y_out] = nearInfectious2(x_in, y_in, states, radius) 

  x_out = []
  y_out = []
  for j=1:length(states)
        if states(j) == "i"
            x_out(end + 1) = x_in(j); % append after the end of the array
            y_out(end + 1) = y_in(j);
        end   
    end 
    disp([x_out])
    disp([y_out]) 

end
```